# Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" because "this.entityManager" is null

Tags: java, jpa, rest-client, helidon

Good afternoon, I am trying to get the data from my database. My application is with abse in microservices which has the following
This is my class for the database configuration.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DbConfig {

@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "db.connection.username")
private String dbUser;

@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "db.connection.password")
private String dbPassword;

@Inject
@ConfigProperty(name = "db.connection.url")
private String dbUrl;

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
 public EntityManager entityManager() {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbUrl);
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser);
        properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPassword);
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-books", properties);
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }
}
```

This is my RepositoryImpl class book

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BookRepositoryImpl implements BookRepository {
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager entityManager;
  @Override
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        try {
            TypedQuery<Book> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Book b ORDER BY b.id ASC", Book.class);
            return query.getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
  ..// another CRUD methods
```

This is my rest class

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/books")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BookRest {
    @GET
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        System.out.println("Buscando todos");
        return bookService.findAll();
    }
..// another CRUD Methods
}
```

The problem arises when I start the application through the server class, it starts correctly at localhost:7001, but in order to verify that it is working correctly I need to list the data in the database through localhost:7001/books, which gives me this error Cannot invoke "jakarta.persistence.EntityManager.createQuery(String, java.lang.Class)" because "this.entityManager" is null

Comment: Is the bookService instance CDI injected? Example is imcomplete

Comment: You may wish to also see https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/wiki/FAQ#jpa-related-topics

Comment: Lastly, I can't tell what version of Helidon MP you're using, but I'll assume 3.x in which case I recommend you read https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/mp/persistence.